# Cuales son las alternativas a getCurrentPosition y a showPosition?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Cree el código para obtener el geoposicionamiento, mediante los métodos de getCurrentPosition y a showPosition. Cuando los subo al servidor me comenta que no es posible porque no encuentra ssl. Cual o cuales serian las alternativas para saber las geolocalizacion de la persona que se conecta a mi sitio web?

Comment: Debe ser un sitio https

Comment: Que otra alternativa puedo hacer?

Comment: Puedes utilizar algún servicio de GeoIP.

Comment: Lo he intentado y no me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la API de geolocalización de Google Maps cuando la conexión segura no esté disponible:

```
var apiGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("¡Se obtuvo la geolocalización con la API con éxito!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var tryAPIGeolocation = function() {
    jQuery.post( "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyDCa1LUe1vOczX1hO_iGYgyo8p_jYuGOPU", function(success) {
        apiGeolocationSuccess({coords: {latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng}});
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    alert("¡Error de Geolocalización en API! \n\n"+err);
  });
};

var browserGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("¡Se obtuvo la localización con éxito!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var browserGeolocationFail = function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("¡Error!\n\n Se agotó el tiempo de espera");
      break;
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      if(error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
        tryAPIGeolocation();
      }
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("¡Error!\n\nPosición no disponible.");
      break;
  }
};

var tryGeolocation = function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        browserGeolocationSuccess,
      browserGeolocationFail,
      {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
  }
};

tryGeolocation();
```

Asegúrate de tener tus "API keys" de Google para poder usar el servicio.

Comment: Hice la prueba y solo me funciona en local.

Comment: @AmauryMeriñoDiaz ¿Qué error te devuelve?

Comment: El server no responde. Error 403.

Comment: @AmauryMeriñoDiaz ¿Sería posible una captura de pantalla?

Comment: Me aparece error de api. Tengo una nueva key de la API y me sale lo mismo. Como envio la captura como comentario?

Comment: @AmauryMeriñoDiaz Tienes dos, editar tu pregunta o subirla a algún alojamiento de imágenes como: https://imgur.com/upload y postear el link como comentario. Ojalá pudieras desplegar bien el error exacto que te da la API y no el general